# Incomplete response received from application when non-ascii character in html

Tags: nginx, ascii

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server with Nginx and Phusion Passenger (non-Rails app) and it is working for websites with ASCII characters in HTML only.

But when I put a non-ascii character to the `index.erb` like `á`, I get error:
`Incomplete response received from application`

My `locale` is:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

All files are in `UTF-8` as well, of course.

Any ideas? I'm out of mine already..

Thanks

Comment: Is the application UNICODE/UTF-8 friendly ? I would start by looking there

Comment: What do you mean UNICODE/UTF-8 friendly? But yes, the application is just few files all UTF-8. Working locally

Comment: I have also set `locale` and rebuild ruby, reinstall gems. No success... :|

Comment: Could it be a miscalculation in the length of the response? Maybe somewhere you use a character length instead of the number of octets?

Comment: No. I have a html page. Put there only one more letter *á* in and it stops working. Delete this one letter and it works again :|